# How to implement an enumerated field using hook_schema()?

Tags: 7, database

I need to have a field in my database that is shall hold a limited set of enumerated values.

The [MySQL ENUM type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html) is not one of the predefined Drupal [data types](https://drupal.org/node/159605).

So how do one implement a field to hold enumerated values using [hook_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7)?

I understand that I can do it with a `tiny int`, but how do I map from and to the strings of enumerated values (e.g. "zero", "one", "two", "three") to integers stored in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Form API to accept this data, you can [map integers to string values](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select).

You can also store that mapping array in your .module file.